# Definition of characteristic

Tags: field-theory, group-homomorphism, positive-characteristic

During one of my lectures my teacher defined the characteristic of a field $F$ as the generator of the kernel of the only homomorphism $\iota: \mathbb{Z}\to F$ that maps $0_{\mathbb{Z}}$ to $0_{F}$ and $1_{\mathbb{Z}}$ to $1_F$. If $F$ is a field, either $\text{char}(F)=0$ or $\text{char}(F)$ is prime because $\mathbb{Z}/\text{ker}(\iota)\cong F$. I suppose he claims this referring to the fundamental homomorphism theorem together with the assumption that $\iota$ is surjective. Why should it be so? The claim seems generally false.

> Does the isomorphism claim hold? If it does, for which reasons? If not, can we modify the assertion somehow to make it true?

Comment: GL2 is not a field, it is not commutative about multiplication.

Comment: I suppose you are assuming that $F$ is finite, right? Also, I don't see why the ring you are considering is a field. Why should the sum of two invertible matrices be invertible?

Comment: Indeed. What a stupid mistake. Fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is false. Indeed the homomorphism clearly isn't surjective in the characteristic 0 case, and it isn't always surjective in the characteristic $p>0$ case either. $\mathbb{Z}/\ker(\iota)$ is isomorphic to the characteristic subfield, in fact this is a possible definition of the characteristic subfield.

The reason we know that $\ker(\iota)=p\mathbb{Z}$ for a prime $p$ is that the image of the homomorphism is a subring of a field, and hence a domain. Thus the kernel is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, and it can be checked that in a PID like $\mathbb{Z}$, the prime ideals are maximal, and thus $\mathbb{Z}/\ker(\iota)$ is a field.

An example where the homomorphism is not surjective in the characteristic $p>0$ case would be with fields such as $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$, like $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2+x+1)$.

Also I feel I should add that $GL_2(F)$ is not a field as the comments have mentioned.

Comment: I just got a chance to accept this answer. Thank you very much, this cleared all my doubts!